# No module named OpenSSL.crypto and ImportError: SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-bigquery

I am trying to connect to the BigQuery API locally with my local dev_appserver, following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization?hl=de#service-accounts 
Running the code mentioned on this site, returns an ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

So I followed the error and spotted (in oauth2client/client.py):

```
if HAS_CRYPTO:
  # PyOpenSSL and PyCrypto are not prerequisites for oauth2client, so if it is
  # missing then don't create the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials or the
  # verify_id_token() method.

  class SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(AssertionCredentials):
```

But I need "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials"! So I isolated the error further and found (in oauth2client/crypt.py) that this line is actually causing this issue:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
```

I tried:

```
$ python
>>> import OpenSSL
>>> OpenSSL.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.pyc'
>>> from OpenSSL import crypto
>>> crypto.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.so'
```

which looks promising and also checked the sys.path of my code:

```
['/Users/mattes/Developer/gae-projects/project123', 
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine', 
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.1.1', 
'/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/yaml-3.10']
```

Anyway, neither adding `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL"` to the sys.path nor symlinking `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL` under `/Users/mattes/Developer/gae-projects/project123` fixes this issue.

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL` looks like:

```
├── SSL.so
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── crypto.so
├── rand.so
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── test_crypto.py
│   ├── test_crypto.pyc
│   ├── test_rand.py
│   ├── test_rand.pyc
│   ├── test_ssl.py
│   ├── test_ssl.pyc
│   ├── util.py
│   └── util.pyc
├── tsafe.py
├── tsafe.pyc
├── version.py
└── version.pyc
```

using Mac 10.9 Mavericks, Python 2.7.5

Can somebody help?

Comment: Where is `oauth2client` module located ? is it inside your apppengine project folder ?

Comment: Yes. Downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-python-client-gae-1.2.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: "The interpreter cannot load Python modules with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment." (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Introduction) So maybe the crypto.so file is the problem?

Comment: "All code for the Python runtime environment must be pure Python, and not include any C extensions or other code that must be compiled." https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Pure_Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding `pycrypto` to `libraries` section in my `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:

- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: What did adding pycrypto to your app.yaml do? Does it force update Python OpenSSL wrappers?

Answer (score 5):

To get this running on the GAE servers I found that three steps were necessary:

1. Install the up-to-date version of the [Google API Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) (or at least the oauth2client module).  Note that they provide a GAE targetted download.
2. Convert my .p12 key file to a .pem format (using the openssl command line tools)

   ```
   openssl pkcs12  -nocerts -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem
   ```
3. Add the PyCrypto library to the app.yaml.

   ```
   libraries:
     - name: pycrypto
       version: "2.6"  # this could be "latest" if you are daring
   ```

For dev_appserver it was also necessary to install the PyCrypto library locally, as it is not contained in the SDK.  (OpenSSL is also supported by the API Client library, but I assume that using PyCrypto stays closer to the runtime environment.)

Comment: For me, `pycparser/__init__.py`, included as a dependency of `PyCrypto`, is trying to import `subprocess.Popen`, and in the App Engine python environment this is failing.  That's causing the `HAS_CRYPTO` check in `oauth2client/client.py` to fail, and so `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` is not being defined.  (I'm using a mac.)

Comment: @EricWalker I have the same issue as you on my Mac. Did you solve it?

Comment: @poiuytrez, it's been a while since I dealt with this problem, but I recall finally getting it to work.  I don't remember what I did.